# How can I know when GLSurfaceView is about to destroy the OpenGL context?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, egl

Is there a way to know when an `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView` class instance is about to destroy its OpenGL context so I could delete my OpenGL resources (shaders, textures, etc.) in a controlled manner? I tried to delete them in the first line of code either in the function `GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory.destroyContext()` or in `GLSurfaceView.EGLWindowSurfaceFactory.destroySurface()` but neither one of those seemed to work because I got this warning in logcat both times:

```
I/com.mydomain.myapp: WindowSurfaceFactory.destroySurface begins
E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
I/com.mydomain.myapp: WindowSurfaceFactory.destroySurface ends
```

So it seems that it's already too late to delete the OpenGL resources because the context seems to have been destroyed already.

I can't use `Activity.onStop()` either because it gets called from a wrong thread.

I guess I could also just forget about the OpenGL resources and just recreate them when the app resumes but then I would have to change my code a lot because I've been using a lot of wrapper classes (in C++) around OpenGL resources that create the resource in the constructor and destroy it in the destructor so there's no quick way to tell them to just forget about the resource. And could I trust that it wouldn't cause memory leaks if I just forgot about those resources?

Comment: Are you aware of setPreserveEGLContextOnPause? It is a common approach to just use that instead of worrying about tearing down/reinitialising OpenGL every time your app goes into the background.

Comment: @Columbo I was aware of that but I thought it was not guaranteed that it works every time. I thought the operating system could discard the context if it wants if it's starting to run out of memory.

Comment: The OS can discard the context but very rarely does IME. It can also terminate your app because it wants the RAM, or because the user changed some system setting, so users are familiar with the fact that there's a chance an app might restart after multitasking.

Comment: @Columbo ok good to know. I fixed this by using setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true); for now. Maybe I don't need to do more if it turns out it's not causing problems on users' devices.